# Javascript convert string to epoch

Tags: javascript

I have the following string format : 2022-10-11 13:54:41.96 and want to convert it to epoch time using JavaScript , i tried the following but get a 'NAN' ,any idea how to convert such string to epoch using javascript?

```
var t ='2022-10-11 13:54:41.96'
var x = new Date(t).getTime()
```

Comment: That isn’t a valid date string

Comment: sorry this i updated the time format

Comment: Well now your code sets x to `1665489281960`, so... voting to close as not reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace " " with the separator "T" and use new Date() with the value.

```
var t ='2022-10-11 13:54:41.96'
var x = new Date(t.replace(" ", "T")).getTime()
console.log(x);
```

If you can control the time in "t" then simple add the separator "T":

```
var t ='2022-10-11T13:54:41.96'
var x = new Date(t).getTime()
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this should do the trick

```
var t ='2022-10-11 13:54:41.96'
var x = Number(new Date(t))
```